# Redirecting to SSL using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have http:// and https:// on the same host like the following:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    listen   443 ssl;

    ...
    ...
}
```

What I need to do is redirecting users who access my shop to `https://`. The problem is I have many languages:

- `https://example.com/en/shop`
- `https://example.com/fr/shop`
- etc...

I tried this and it didn't work `(nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed)`:

```
if ($server_port = 80) {
    location (en|fr)/shop {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use regular expressions for matching [`location`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)s, you need to prefix the expression with either `~` or `~*`:

```
if ($server_port = 80) {
    location ~ (en|fr)/shop {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> To use regular expressions, you must use a prefix:
>
> 1. `"~"` for case sensitive matching
> 2. `"~*"` for case insensitive matching

Since nginx does't allow `location` blocks to be nested inside of `if` blocks, try the following configuration:

```
if ($server_port = 80) {
    rewrite ^/(en|fr)/shop https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: I got another error with your code: Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in

Comment: @AdamSilver:   You cannot have `location` inside of an `if` block (see location's documentation).  Simply change you rewrite rule to only rewrite if the path starts with `(en|fr)/shop`.

Comment: But I'll get a redirect loop!

Comment: @AdamSilver:  You shouldn't.  You keep your `if`, but only nest a `rewrite` inside of it.

Answer (score 47):

It would also be more of an Nginx best practice to do a 301 redirect instead of using the if statement (see Server name on http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).  I created a gist with an `nginx.conf` configured for SSL, Rails and Unicorn

https://gist.github.com/Austio/6399964

Here would be the relevant section for yours.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: (Sorry for digging an old thread) To avoid bad practice, I think this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: instead of hard code domain name, we can do: return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

Answer (score 11):

Or better yet, avoiding the hardcoded server name

```
server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite (.*) https://$http_host$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, avoiding if statements while preserving the trailing path:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite (.*) https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

**permanent** takes care of the 301.

Answer (score 2):

another way with error_page 497

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
...
```