# Nginx (1.2.7) redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: http, redirect, ssl, nginx, https

On my server http is installed **Nginx version: 1.2.7**

Today I turned on SSL.

But I have a big problem, i do not know how to set the absolute all subpages diverted permanently to: `https://example.com`

So I want all this:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`

to be redirected to `https://example.com`

- `http://www.example.com/test.pdf`
  to be redirected to `https://example.com/test.pdf`

Like **all subpages** (I have 500 sub pages 200 html – 300 pdf).

On my https installed Apache.

**Also how to configure everything, because I have very little knowledge.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting to SSL using nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523180/redirecting-to-ssl-using-nginx).

Answer (score 0):

try this: return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;